# How to mount USB wireless adapter on Debian

Tags: debian, wifi

I am running Debian Jessie 8.9 and want to use the Netgear A6210 wireless adapter.  I install the driver [here](https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210)
.  Afterwards, what should I do to use my wifi adapter?  Using lsinput does not show the wifi adapter, only the keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Since the device seems to be a USB wireless dongle, you may want to try `lsusb -t`

Comment: did you have a look on AskUbuntu whether the problem has [maybe been already solved there](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Netgear+A6210)?

Comment: lsbusb hangs up, nothing shows.  That is why I use lsinput.